# Angular PayPal Processing, Childcomponent and Lifecycle

Tags: javascript, angular, paypal, paypal-sandbox

I am currently working on the PayPal integration in my own shop (Angular Frontend, dotnet core WebApi backend) and apparently I have a problem with the life cycle between the main component (CheckoutProcessComponent) and the child component (PaymentPayPalComponent) and with the use of the necessary PayPal javascript.

Basically the complete PayPal workflow works as long as I use static variables. And this is exactly where my problem starts.

CheckoutProcessComponent.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { CartService } from 'src/app/_services/shop/cart.service';
import { ISubscriptionCollection } from 'src/app/_models/misc/ISubscriptionCollection';
import { serialUnsubscriber } from 'src/app/shared/utility.module';
import { CheckoutService } from 'src/app/_services/checkout/checkout.service';
import { ICheckoutOrderData } from 'src/app/_models/shop/ICheckoutOrderData';
import { IOrderProcessSummary } from 'src/app/_models/shop/IOrderProcessSummary';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-checkout-process',
  templateUrl: './checkout-process.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./checkout-process.component.css']
})
export class CheckoutProcessComponent implements OnInit {
  subscriptions: ISubscriptionCollection = {};

  checkoutOrderData = {} as ICheckoutOrderData;
  orderSummaryFromServer: IOrderProcessSummary;
  orderCreated: boolean = false;

  constructor(public checkoutService: CheckoutService, public cartService: CartService) { }

  ngOnInit() {    
    this.checkoutOrderData.Order = this.checkoutService.orderData;
    this.checkoutOrderData.Cart = this.cartService.shoppingCart;
    // Create Order
    this.subscriptions['createOrder'] = this.checkoutService.createOrder(this.checkoutOrderData)
      .subscribe((res: IOrderProcessSummary) => {
        this.checkoutService.checkoutSummary = res;
        this.orderSummaryFromServer = res;
        console.log('Order created: ' + res);
      }, error => {
        console.log('Error');
      });
  }

  ngOnDestroy(): void {
    serialUnsubscriber(...Object.values(this.subscriptions));
  }

  nextStep(step: number) {
    this.checkoutService.updateCheckoutStep(step);
  }
 ...
}
```

CheckoutProcessComponent.html

```
<app-payment-paypal [orderSummary]="orderSummaryFromServer" *ngIf="checkoutService.orderData.paymentMethod === 'PM_PAYPAL'"></app-payment-paypal>
<app-payment-stripe *ngIf="checkoutService.orderData.paymentMethod === 'PM_STRIPE'"></app-payment-stripe>
<app-payment-moneytransfer *ngIf="checkoutService.orderData.paymentMethod === 'PM_TRANSFER'"></app-payment-moneytransfer>
```

PaymentPayPalComponent.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit, AfterViewChecked, Input } from '@angular/core';
import { environment } from 'src/environments/environment';
import { IOrderProcessSummary } from 'src/app/_models/shop/IOrderProcessSummary';
import { CheckoutService } from 'src/app/_services/checkout/checkout.service';

declare let paypal: any;

@Component({
  selector: 'app-payment-paypal',
  templateUrl: './payment-paypal.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./payment-paypal.component.css']
})
export class PaymentPaypalComponent implements OnInit, AfterViewChecked {
  @Input() orderSummary: IOrderProcessSummary;

  paypalClientId = environment.paymentPayPal.clientId;
  addScript: boolean = false;
  scriptTagElement: HTMLScriptElement;
  constructor(private checkoutService: CheckoutService) { }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

  ngOnDestroy(): void {
    if (this.scriptTagElement) {
      document.body.removeChild(this.scriptTagElement);
    }
  }

  ngAfterViewChecked(): void {
    if (!this.addScript) {
      this.addPayPalScript().then(() => {
        paypal.Buttons({
          createOrder: function() {
            return fetch('https://localhost:5021/api/payments/paypal-create-order', {
              method: 'post',
              headers: {
                'content-type': 'application/json'
              },
              body: JSON.stringify({
                orderId: 1234
              })
            }).then(function(res) {
              return res.json();
            }).then(function(data) {
              return data.id; // Use the same key name for order ID on the client and server
            });
          },
          onApprove: function(data, actions) {
            console.log('onApprove - transaction was approved, but not authorized', data, actions);
            actions.order.get().then(details => {
                    console.log('onApprove - you can get full order details inside onApprove: ', details);
            });

            return fetch('https://localhost:5021/api/payments/paypal-capture-order', {
              method: 'post',
              headers: {
                'content-type': 'application/json'
              },
              body: JSON.stringify({
                token:   data.orderID,
                payerID: data.payerID,
              })
            });
          },
          onClientAuthorization: (data) => {
            console.log('onClientAuthorization - you should probably inform your server about completed transaction at this point', data);
            // this.showSuccess = true;
          },
          onCancel: (data, actions) => {
            console.log('OnCancel', data, actions);
            // this.showCancel = true;
          },
          onError: err => {
            console.log('OnError', err);
            // this.showError = true;
          }
        }).render('#paypal-button-container');
      })
    }
  }

  addPayPalScript() {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      this.scriptTagElement = document.createElement('script');
      this.scriptTagElement.src = 'https://www.paypal.com/sdk/js?currency=EUR&client-id=' + this.paypalClientId;
      this.scriptTagElement.onload = resolve;
      document.body.appendChild(this.scriptTagElement);
      this.addScript = true;
    })
  }

}
```

PaymentPayPalComponent.html

```
<div class="text-center" id="paypal-button-container"></div>
```

The processing flow is as follows:

1. CheckoutProcessComponent > creates the order on the server with the cart data and stores the order in the database (general function, non PayPal related)
2. The result from 1. is of IOrderProcessSummary which holds the order Id and the total of the order
3. Depending on the selected payment method, the corresponding payment-Child Component will be displayed. In this case the PaymentPayPalComponent.
4. Then I use the PayPal-feature "CreatePayPalOrderOnServer" which uses the PayPal Api in my backend to create an order on the PayPal server. But for that I need the specific orderId because I need to fill the PayPal-Order data with the specific order data from my system (in the example I have a fixed 1234 order Id).

For step 4. I tried it with Input()-parameter and with injecting the CheckoutService to the PaymentPayPalComponent but I am not able to work with any kind of dynamic variables within the PayPal-Button-Function (JavaScript). In the example I need to change the "orderId: 1234" with a value from the Input() orderSummary or the same value from the CheckoutService, but both of them stay undefined.

The PayPal-Javascript is loaded correctly and the PayPal-Buttons show up and work as intended technically.

How do I bring my dynamic data into the PaymentPayPalComponent and into the PayPal.Buttons-Function?

Thanks for your tips!